# Ubuntu One doesn't start after login

Tags: 10.10, ubuntu-one, 64-bit

On my Desktop (ubuntu 10.10 64 Bit) Ubuntu One doesn't start after login. I have to start the UbuntuOne Preferences, than I have to wait a while until the connect butten is enabled and than I can connect. How can I start it after login?

Answer (score 4):

The Ubuntu One launcher delays 30 seconds after session startup before starting the syncdaemon. The syncdaemon can then take a few minutes before it's alive and well and answering requests. So, if you wait 30 seconds after startup, you should be able to open a terminal and see the process with `ps -C ubuntuone-syncdaemon`.

If you find that it *isn't* starting, in that same terminal, please do

```
/usr/lib/ubuntuone-client/ubuntuone-syncdaemon --debug
```

and pastebin the output so we can get to the root of the issue.

Comment: With ps -C ubuntuone-syncdaemon I can see, that the syncdaemon is not running. The Debug output is to much to paste here. I have to forward the output into a file. I will do this after next reboot

Answer (score 3):

Make sure it is enabled in System -> Preferences -> Startup Applications

[image: Startup Applications]

Comment: It is enabled..

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I made some tests. Directly after the login I called the "ps" command. ubuntuone-syncd is running. I try it again a few minutes later, but syncd has stopped.

Than I run syncd with --debug and here is the Logfile (4,3MB)

http://ubuntuone.com/p/PW1/