# Unable to connect to Ubuntu One

Tags: ubuntu-one

I am having trouble connecting to Ubuntu One.  I have gone to **System > Preferences > Ubuntu One** and entered my account information.  All seems well at this point.  Then when I go to the **Devices** tab and click **Connect**, it grays out for about 3 seconds and does nothing.

I have tried reinstalling, rebooting, removing the machine from my account without any success.

Any ideas on other things to try?

*FYI*: I'm using Ubuntu 10.10.

Comment: I'm having similar problems. Try using `u1sdtool --status` to see what results you get. I'm getting errors.

Comment: Installing and running `magicicada` is also generally a really good bet for u1 problems - it shows you what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tracked down how to fix the problem.  It appears that this is somewhat of a known bug.  I was able to solve the problem by disconnecting the Ubuntu One account from the computer (by removing the computer from the account) and then deleting the `Ubuntu One` folder and `~/.local/share/ubuntuone` folder, it cleared all of the configuration and when I reconnected the account, all was well.

Answer (score 0):

1. Log in at: https://one.ubuntu.com/ 
   If you succeed, it means that the login details are correct.
2. Check it out:

   - logs (eg messages),
   - firewall (?)
3. Install Wireshak and check traffic to the server and Ubuntu One

Comment: 1. I am able to login to one.ubuntu.com, so I know the login details are correct.
2. The firewall is disabled, but I am unsure where to find the log files?
3. I'm not sure what I should be looking for in Wireshark (I've never used it).

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1486490

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/12848/ubuntu-one-doesnt-start-after-login